# Encoding issue with ASCII-safe file with codec header, depending on line count

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, encoding, python-3.5

Here is magical bug of Python 3.5.2 on Windows that killed my day. File below fails on this system:

> ```
> C:\Python35\python.exe encoding-problem-cp1252.py
>  File "encoding-problem-cp1252.py", line 2
> SyntaxError: encoding problem: cp1252
> ```

Contains almost nothing - apart from the `coding` header there are a bunch of empty lines, but **when any line is removed**, even an empty one, it works again. I thought that it is a local problem, so I setup [job on AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/techtonik/testbin/build/1.0.2) that showed the same behavior.

What's going on with Python?

There is a [binary accurate version](https://github.com/techtonik/testbin/commit/fbb8aec3650b45f690c4febfd621fe5d6892b14a#diff-9583069b05ef628abe1dda1ae5962a43) of the file below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-


"""
There is nothing in this file, except that it is more
than 50 lines long. Running it with Python 3.5.2 on
Windows gives the following error:

    >python encoding-problem-cp1252.py
      File "encoding-problem-cp1252.py", line 2
    SyntaxError: encoding problem: cp1252

    >python
    Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

If you remove any lines from this file, it will
execute successfully.
"""



def restore(dump):
  """













  """
  return



def main():
  print('ok')



if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Not running on windows, this is hard to debug; the file runs fine on Mac OS X and Linux. Sounds like you found a bug, please file one at http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: Looking over the [relevant source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Parser/tokenizer.c#l510) I am suspicious of the CRLF handling there. What happens if you converted the file from Unix line endings (as it is now) to Windows line endings? The file being longer certainly would fit with a buffering issue.

Comment: Could somebody fill this bug for me? I am banned from this tracker for too emotional responses in the lists some years ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, when file is converted to CRLF, the bug is gone, but I am not going to convert all my sources to CRLF, because Windows is secondary platform for those scripts.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hunch was correct.

Comment: Reported at http://bugs.python.org/issue27797

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for reporting. I am sure it will save days for people who run into this issue just like me. Encodings even without bugs are not sweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a regression caused by [issue #20731](http://bugs.python.org/issue20731). It looks like the position calculation is assuming there will always be CRLF line endings while your file has only got LF characters, leading to an incorrect offset [being calculated here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Parser/tokenizer.c#l510):

```c
fd = fileno(tok->fp);
/* Due to buffering the file offset for fd can be different from the file
 * position of tok->fp.  If tok->fp was opened in text mode on Windows,
 * its file position counts CRLF as one char and can't be directly mapped
 * to the file offset for fd.  Instead we step back one byte and read to
 * the end of line.*/
pos = ftell(tok->fp);
if (pos == -1 ||
    lseek(fd, (off_t)(pos > 0 ? pos - 1 : pos), SEEK_SET) == (off_t)-1) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrnoWithFilename(PyExc_OSError, NULL);
    goto cleanup;
}
```

The problem disappears when you convert your file to use Windows (CRLF) line endings, but I can understand that for cross-platform scripts that's not a practical solution.

I've filed [issue #27797](http://bugs.python.org/issue27797); this should be fixed in Python itself.

Comment: The problem is that `ftell(tok->fp)` returns -1. The number of newlines needed to trigger the bug depends on the length of the shebang and coding spec. To calculate the file position `ftell` subtracts the count of unread bytes in the buffer from the actual OS file position. The problem is that line endings in the buffer have already been translated to LF, while the OS file position is based on untranslated lines endings. So `ftell` assumes the file uses CRLF line endings and thus subtracts 2 bytes per unread LF. With the right conditions it returns -1, which looks like an error.

Comment: Someone else? ;-) BTW, I only looked at these specific cases that make `ftell` return -1. It can also return a position less than -1, in which case the `lseek` call is what fails because it's `SEEK_SET`.

Comment: @eryksun: oops! Thanks for doing the analysis!